# Striking statistics on the SOLID principles

Tags: software, research, medium

I'm writing an article about software quality and SOLID on Medium. I want to add statistics (reports, surveys etc.) to strengthen my article. For example;

> According to research of company X, the annual cost of technical debt
> to companies due to violation of principles such as SOLID is around $
> 1.6 per line for 2019.

Are there websites where I can find research, reports, metrics like this?

Thanks for your answer in advance.

Comment: While generally about writing, you might have better luck finding suggestions on a stackexchange closer to the topic, like https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ or https://sqa.stackexchange.com/, although I'm not sure such a question would be on topic there.

Comment: Hi Mustafa, welcome to writing.se! Take our [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. This is a nice first question and one that is technically on topic for our site. However as Llewellyn points out you might get better answers on a more dedicated data/statistics site. If you like I can migrate your question to [OpenData.SE], [SQA.SE] or [SoftwareEngineering.SE]. Good luck and happy writing!